# Minify NodeJS project files

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

I'm wonder if minifying my server-side JavaScript files is good for my NodeJS app performance?

I'm doing it all the time for the client-side JS + CSS files but i curious if doing it for the files the NodeJS app running is necessary?

Thanks.